# OpenCV 2.4.13.4 dll link error

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, opencv

I am running the following code snippet for OpenCV:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

System.out.println("Welcome to OpenCV " + Core.VERSION);
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
Mat m  = Mat.eye(3, 3, CvType.CV_8UC1);
System.out.println("m = " + m.dump());
}
```

I get this error:

```
Welcome to OpenCV 2.4.13.4
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_eye(III)J
    at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_eye(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.core.Mat.eye(Mat.java:1468)
    at HelloCV.main(HelloCV.java:29)
```

I have tried the following:

1. Putting the dll full path name on System.loadLibrary
2. Passing the dll path to JVM
3. Putting the dll file into the windows system32 folder
4. Putting the dll path name into eclipse opencv.jar config

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was an issue with the following eclipse version:

```
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)
Build id: 20171005-1200
OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
```

The below eclipse version works:

```
Eclipse SDK

Version: Neon (4.6)
Build id: I20160606-1100
```